# Convert an anchor to button

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a simple question how to convert `<a href="">` to `<button>` ?

I do that because I don't want user to see the link url.

example :

```
<a href="#<?php echo $msg_id=$data['msg_id']; ?>" title="Comment" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/comments.png"/></a>
```

Now how can I convert that into button ?

```
<button></button>
```

Comment: changing a link in a button will not change a thing. If I want to see the URL, I just go to the source. You are making things needlesly complex. In the end, when the user goes through the link, it will see the URL anyway. Just my 2p.

Comment: An (ab)use maybe to hide something like this: badsite.com?track=url_encoded with a instant redirection

Comment: What's wrong with the question ? -2 ? See the question carefully please

Comment: I think that the reason for the down-votes is a mix of the dubious motivation expressed and the fact that your question does not show any serious effort to solve the problem. "Do my work for me"-questions are usually frowned upon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using bootstrap and you want to trigger a modal using `<button>`. Here's a sample from the bootstrap documentation:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

If I apply it to your code,

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $msg_id=$data['msg_id'];?>" title="Comment"><img src="images/comments.png"/></button>
```

Comment: That looks more like it assuming you are correct with bootstrap which I have not used

Comment: I added bootstrap to the tags of your question

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="window.location='URL'">button text</button>
```

.. but they will be able to see the url inspecting html page' code!

Comment: and of course see the location bar content when the page loads - can whoever downvoted please say why?

Comment: Maybe to hide something like this: *badsite.com?track=url_encoded* with a instant redirection

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is that when the button is clicked, it should open the same URL that was present in href. If this is the scenario, you can just add an onclick event handler to the button i.e onclick="navigate('*Your URL here*');".

You can also set the onclick event to call a javascript function which in turn can open a modal/normal popup window for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
<form><input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.ch/'" /></form>
```

Put your text you want for `value` and put your URL in `window.location.href=''`.

If you want it with `<button></button>` this could be another way:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.ch/'">Click me</button>
```